# How to make loop buy max amount?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to my make my code buy the Max amount of Phones and Accessories. One Phone costs 99.99 and an Accessory costs 9.99. I have 1000 on my bank account. How do i make my code buy the max amount? My code buys currently 9 phones and 9 accessories. It should buy 9 phones and 10 accessories instead 9.

```js
const ACCESSORY = 9.99;
const PHONE = 99.99;

var balance = 1000;
var total = 0;

var phones_total = 0;
var accessories_total = 0;

while (((total + PHONE) || (total + ACCESSORY)) < balance) {
  total = total + PHONE;
  phones_total = phones_total + 1;
    if ((total + ACCESSORY) < balance) {
      total = total + ACCESSORY;
      accessories_total = accessories_total + 1;
    }
}

console.log("total = " + total);
console.log("phones = " + phones_total);
console.log("accessories = " + accessories_total);
```

Comment: 10 phones + 10 accessories costs 1099.80, which is more than you can afford.

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem better.

Comment: `while (((total + PHONE) || (total + ACCESSORY)) < balance)` is not correct. It should be `while ((total + PHONE) < balance || (total + ACCESSORY) < balance)`

Comment: Oops, i meant 9 phones and 10 accessories.

Comment: @barmar nope that didn't work, total is 1089,91 now - which is over 1000 treshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
while (((total + PHONE) || (total + ACCESSORY)) < balance) {
```

This doesn't test whether either sum is less than `balance`. The value of `(total + PHONE) || (total + ACCESSORY)` is always `total + PHONE` unless that's `0`, then it's `total + ACCESSORY`. And since `total + PHONE` is never `0`, this is effectively equivalent to:

```
while ((total + PHONE) < balance) {
```

and it never tests whether there's available balance for just an accessory. The correct way to do this test is:

```
while ((total + PHONE) < balance || (total + ACCESSORY) < balance) {
```

You also should be using `<=` rather than `<`, to allow for using all your money exactly.

But then inside the loop, you still add `PHONE` to `total`, even if there was only enough balance left for an accessory. You need to check first.

```js
const ACCESSORY = 9.99;
const PHONE = 99.99;

var balance = 1000;
var total = 0;

var phones_total = 0;
var accessories_total = 0;

while ((total + PHONE) <= balance || (total + ACCESSORY) <= balance) {
   if ((total + PHONE) <= balance) {
     total = total + PHONE;
     phones_total = phones_total + 1;
   }
   if ((total + ACCESSORY) <= balance) {
     total = total + ACCESSORY;
     accessories_total = accessories_total + 1;
   }
 }

console.log(phones_total, accessories_total);
```

A simpler way to do it is with arithmetic instead of a loop. Divide the balance by the cost of a phone + accessory, to find out the number of pairs you can afford. Then find out how many more accessories you can buy with what's left after that.

```js
const ACCESSORY = 9.99;
const PHONE = 99.99;

var balance = 1000;

var phones_total = Math.floor(balance/(PHONE + ACCESSORY));
var remainder = balance - phones_total*(PHONE+ACCESSORY)
var accessories_total = phones_total + Math.floor(remainder/ACCESSORY);

console.log(phones_total, accessories_total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
const ACCESSORY = 9.99;
const PHONE = 99.99;

var balance = 1000;
var total = 0;

var phones_total = 0;
var accessories_total = 0;

while (((total + PHONE) < balance) || ((total + ACCESSORY) < balance)) {
    if((total + PHONE) < balance){
        total = total + PHONE;
        phones_total = phones_total + 1;
    }
    if ((total + ACCESSORY) < balance) {
        total = total + ACCESSORY;
        accessories_total = accessories_total + 1;
    }
}

console.log("total = " + total);
console.log("phones = " + phones_total);
console.log("accessories = " + accessories_total);
```

But with that balance you can only buy 9 phones and 10 accesories.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop condition, you only need to check if you have money left over for an accessory. If you don't, there is no need to execute the body.

```
while ((total + ACCESSORY) <= balance) {
    if ( (total + PHONE) <= balance) {
        ++ phones_total;
        total = (phones_total * PHONE) + (accessories_total * ACCESSORY);
    }

    if ( (total + ACCESSORY) <= balance) {
        ++ accessories_total;
        total = (phones_total * PHONE) + (accessories_total * ACCESSORY);
    }
}
```

In the body, first check if there is money for a phone, if so update totals, then see if you still have money for an accessory.

With floating point numbers, adding them over and over is going to lead to more cumulative error than simply calculating the `total` as above.